# In which method to set child view controllers when subclassing UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a subclass of UIViewController that always initially loads the same "master" and "detail" child view controllers. I'm wondering if `viewDidLoad` is the best place to set these view controllers? Thanks for reading.

Comment: What other method would you use?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to better understand the ideal methods (e.g., init, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear) in which to place my view controller setup code. (In general, trying to shorten the list of things I code out of habit without understanding the reasons!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably yes. Note that the `viewDidLoad` method gets executed only once, when the `UIViewController`s are presented to the user.